# How are illusionary walls working?

Tags: dark-souls-3

In Dark Souls 1 illusions could be detected by rolling into them or hitting them. In Dark Souls 2 you had to press the "Activate" key to remove illusions.

How does this gameplay mechanic work in Dark Souls III? How can you remove illusions like secret doors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, there are some, and just like in the first one, you have to HIT the wall.

Edit: It looks like rolling though it works too.

Take care of player's notes, most of these are a troll. :)

[If you want some other witnesses](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168566-dark-souls-iii/73574287)

Comment: So rolling does not work, only hitting (and decreasing weapon durability)? Don't worry about the trolls, I don't trust any message on a cliff saying "Treasure ahead". :)

Comment: Yes, you need to Hit, pretty sure rolling doesn't work (can't try it right now ), if you worry about your weapon durability, just go like me with a "wall-hitter", some kind of fast and light weapon (dagger for instance) that you smash everywhere (Yeh, you look really dump playing dark souls :) )

Comment: Rolling works, at least for the one I've found. And people on Reddit have said the same.

Comment: I apology for my comment then. Too late for me to edit it.